# Python Anaconda Command prompt through Putty Connected Command Prompt

Tags: python, pip, package, anaconda, conda

Is there a way to run the Anaconda Command Prompt through the command line of a machine that I have connected through Putty?

My main goal is to install a 'tar.gz' package offline. From what I've understood from stackoverflow posts is that I have downloaded the pip version and not the Anaconda version of the package. The machine I am connected is not open to internet and I need to install a lot of packages offline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load the Anaconda Command Prompt to install packages.

Even when installing a local package with `conda` it will check for the packages existence in the default channels. So not having an internet connection is problematic with `conda`.

You are correct that `pip` is the way to go for local packages. You simply need to run:

```
pip install /path/to/your/pacakage.tar.gz
```

Obviously you should ensure that the environment you want to install the package in is currently activated before installing with `pip`. e.g. `conda activate some_env`

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo. My concern is that pip install <package> won’t install it to Anaconda’s environment. Would I have to switch to the default environment with the activate command?

Comment: It will install to your currently active anaconda environment.

Comment: In other words, would I be able to import the package I’ve “pip install”’ed in my Anaconda Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes. I do this when I have a custom packages that I don't want in our corporate cloud and especially not in the anaconda public repository.

Comment: I see. I’m not at my office so I can’t test it but I will definitely try on Monday and check off your answer. Thank you very much!